# Hide/Unhide an image using jquery on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 `<a>` tags in my html and they each contain 2 images. Only the grescale images are displayed and the other ones are set to none.

I want to hide the greyscale image when I hover the mouse over the grescale image and display the colored one. And when I un-hover I want the colored image to be hidden again. How can I do that using jquery?

```
<a class="mylink" href="">
    <img src="img/thumbnails/colored-1.jpg" class="color-image"/>
    <img src="img/thumbnails/greyscale-1.jpg" class="greyscale-image"/>
</a>

<a class="mylink" href="">
    <img src="img/thumbnails/colored-2.jpg" class="color-image"/>
    <img src="img/thumbnails/greyscale-2.jpg" class="greyscale-image"/>
</a>

<a class="mylink" href="">
    <img src="img/thumbnails/colored-3.jpg" class="color-image"/>
    <img src="img/thumbnails/greyscale-3.jpg" class="greyscale-image"/>
</a>

.color-image
{
    display:none
}
```

Comment: As the highest upvoted answer says, you don't need JQuery to control CSS based on hover

Answer (score 4):

Why use jQuery and not pure CSS?

You can use :hover and toggle the display of the images.

```
a.mylink:hover .color-image,
a.mylink .greyscale-image {
   display: inline;
}

a.mylink .color-image,
a.mylink:hover .greyscale-image {
   display: none;
}
```

In jQuery it is just

```
function swap(evt) {
    var isOver = evt.type === "mouseenter";
    link.find(".color-image").toggle(isOver);
    link.find(".greyscale-image").toggle(!isOver);
}

$("a.mylink").hover(swap, swap);
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I wanted to add a transition effect to it? I can still do it in css?

Comment: There are CSS transitions

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm stuck I wish I could get a hint on how to write this in jquery.

Comment: Why are you so adamant on using JQuery? Just doing a quick search for `CSS Transition Effect Examples` comes back with plenty of results. Doing this in JQuery is more fiddly to accommodate different scenarios where as the above example (minus a few tweaks for transition) will do it all for you.

Comment: @Damian I searched but I couldn't find the one that suits this situation. I come from C# programming background and I'm totally new to these stuff.

Comment: So I added the code that uses hover. I did not add transitions since that is not in the scope of the original question. You can figure out how to use jQuery transitions. Just a warning, it is not as simple as calling fade.

Comment: No matter if you still want to use Jquery for the transitions, at then end JQuery will apply css transitions, so why bothering in using a third party if what ever this is doing at the end can be applied without it!

Answer (score 2):

NO Jquery needed. Use the `:hover` css pseudo on the `.myLink` anchor, like:

```
.color-image {
    display:none;
}

a.myLink:hover .color-image {
    display: block;
}

a.myLink:hover .greyscale-image {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My way :p

```
a[class="mylink"]:not(:hover) img[class*="greyscale"],
a[class="mylink"]:hover img[class*="color"] {
    display: inline-block;
}
a[class="mylink"]:not(:hover) img[class*="color"],
a[class="mylink"]:hover img[class*="greyscale"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Here is a demo JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/agaex70r/

Here is another JSFiddle with a transition.

http://jsfiddle.net/agaex70r/2/

Comment: `a[class="mylink"]:not(:hover)` Yikes

Comment: @espascarello haven't u ever hear about this type of classes?

Comment: It is overkill and expensive. All of your selectors in the example are way overkill.

Comment: @Allan The answer works but I'm using the bootstap and when implementing this for some very odd reason the first image hides and the second one jumps and displays in another location!

Comment: I don't know why people are using that Bootstap or what ever, it limits the user so much and you need to play with their rules. it's much better to use the real thing. Well That's what I like to think.

Comment: Why do you need to use Bootstap or whatever?

Comment: Try using the demo from my second JSFiddle link

Comment: @Allan I used that one, it is not working :( I love the puppies by the way ;)

Comment: post a JSfiddle with your code and let see whats happening in there :p, and yes, PUPPIES!

Comment: My website is based on bootstrap, does JSFiddle support it?

Comment: @Vahid, share your website then I will use google chrome's Inspector

Comment: @Allan I think one reason may be that you have used translates and absolute positions in your css. That's interfering with bootsrap's responsiveness and thus the odd behavior.

Comment: @Allan It is still on my hard drive :p

Comment: @Vahid, well, if you dont mind sharing your code via link/zip or something I think I iwll be able to help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60999/discussion-between-vahid-and-allan).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with css:hover. Hover on gray scale image, display:none and the reverse for the colored image. This has the benefit of working when JS is disabled. Otherwise, you could look into Jquery UI